# Adding drop shadow (with params color, x, y and blur) in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, shadow

I'm developping an app in Android Studio, and I'm trying to set a design that I've done in Adobe XD.

My issue is with the shadows I have created is my design. Let me show you what I want to do :

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uJMi.png)

I would like to be able to set a shadow to a shape, and setting the color, the x and y positions, and the blur of the shadow.

I have tried some things, but nothing seems to work out as I want.

Hope to get some help! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example I have used in many projects. Just add this **dependency** in you **project gradle**

```
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.1'
```

and follow this **GitHub** url : https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView